# How to write a function in JavaScript on the basis of URL which contains productID , TariffID, AccessoriesID

Tags: javascript

I have a URL say : (https://www.a.b.com/shop/tariff) when I select some items from it and they generate productID,planId,accessories(multiple),contractType,planCategory when I click on "Add to Cart" when I come back it has URL as below, and it is not selecting items on the basis of ID's :

E.g.
(https://www.x.y.z/shop/tariff/item/item1?productId=x&planId=y&accessories=z1,Z2&contractType=paymonthly&planCategory=normal)

How to write a function in JavaScript to select all the items on the basis of ID's like x,y,z1,z2?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: can you show the code that you attempted this with? It is much easier and preferred to help you alter your code rather than write it from scratch.

Comment: @AndrewLohr, mucha gracias ! for trying to help . But, I do not have it handy now and I can't share it . But , I would like to thank you for your time on my post . Hope, you understood my question .

Answer (score 0):

**Code snippet:**

```
var queryParam = [];
location.search.substr(1).split("&").forEach(function (item) {
    var key = item.split("=")[0],
        value = item.split("=")[1],
        obj = {};
    obj[key] = value;
    queryParam.push(obj);
});
queryParam.forEach(function (object) {
    //get your item by each query param here
    //and put your code to select the item here
});
```

Comment: First of all I would like to appreciate you for your efforts. You're absolutely correct in doing it (I did in same manner) , but I forgot to mention that we are fetching that URL from server side scripting using PHP. So, what exactly my need is now is like I have to work on that URL when I come back from my "add to cart" page to selected item page but it is getting deselected and I have to make it selected based on URL because URL is not changing after coming back to that page but items are getting deselected and I have to replicate this issue. Thank you for your help .